# captureScreenshotOnFailure not working, broken

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit, screenshot

I can't get these screenshots working for the life of me:

- The directories exist
- The test executes (and fails) as expected
- I'm using Firefox (14.1)
- Read the docs (only a few paragraphs)
- I've read everything I can find:

  - http://www.devinzuczek.com/2011/08/taking-a-screenshot-with-phpunit-and-selenium-rc/
  - [PHPUnit Selenium captureScreenshotOnFailure does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847048/phpunit-selenium-capturescreenshotonfailure-does-not-work)
  - lots of others

Should be pretty simple, but there's no error messages, nothing.  Can anyone shed some light before I start digging into the source?

```
class ScreenshotTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase {
    protected $captureScreenshotOnFailure = TRUE;
    protected $screenshotPath = 'C:\\';
    protected $screenshotUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/';

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://127.0.0.1/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->url('http://127.0.0.1');
        $this->assertEquals('foobarbaz', $this->title());
    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha - found the problem.

```
extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
```

should be

```
extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
```

Gotcha!

The first example in the documentation is for `PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase`.  All of the others on the page are for `PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase`.

*Edit*

This question started me on one of those search-for-answers-for-days struggles.  For the next guy/gal having this trouble, there's a few beginner-level headaches that aren't explicitly stated anwhere and I documented them at [Where the heck is any Selenium 2 documentation for PHPUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106365/).